# Manipulate two graphs with one parameter

Tags: plotting, manipulate, slider

This question is related to a previous question [Create a slider to illustrate Fubini theorem.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213358/create-a-slider-to-illustrate-fubini-theorem)

Thank to the help of @kglr, now I can create sliders to control the slice.

```
 ClearAll[a, B1, B2, B3, B4];

B4[a_?NumericQ] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{a, y, z}, {y, 
   3 + (-8 + a)* (1/13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + a))*(5 + a)), 
   4.8 + Sin[a]}, {z, 0, 0.01*(a + 5)^2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Mesh -> 20, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.4], Thickness[0.06], 
    Specularity[White, 30]]];(*The blue plane*)

B1 = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 0.01*(x + 5)^2}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, 
   3 + (-8 + x) (1/13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + x))*(5 + x)), 
   4.8 + Sin[x]}, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.8], 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]]];

B2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 
    3 + (-8 + x) (1/13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + x))*(5 + x)), 
    z}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 0.01*(x + 5)^2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.1], 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]]];

B3 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 4.8 + Sin[x], z}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 
    0.01*(x + 5)^2}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> 20, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[.1], 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Red, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 30]]];

t1 = Manipulate[
   Show[B1, B2, B3, B4[a], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.3}], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}];

t2 = Plot[{4.8 + Sin[x], 
    3 + (-8 + x) (1/13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + x))*(5 + x))}, {x, -5, 
    5}, PlotRange -> {1.7, 6}];

t3[a_?NumericQ] := 
  Plot[100* Sign[x - a], {x, -5, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {3 + (-8 + a) (1/
         13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + a))*(5 + a)), 4.8 + Sin[a]}];

t4 = Manipulate[Show[t2, t3[a]], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}];


 Grid[{{t1, t4}}, ItemSize -> {{30, 30}}, Frame -> All, 
     FrameStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

**My question:** How can we create only one slider for $a$ to control two graphs? The parameter $a$ for the picture on the left is used for the plane $x=a$ (the blue plane), while the same $a$ is for the line $x=a$ on the right hand side picture. That is, we will have the following illustration.

[image]

Thank for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

#### Code

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1[x_] := 4.8 + Sin[x]
f2[x_] := 3 + (-8 + x) (1/13 + (0.01 + 0.0022*(-4 + x))*(5 + x))
f3[x_] := 0.01*(x + 5)^2

viewpoint = {-2.7, 1.6, 1.3};

plt1 = Plot3D[f3[x], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 2, 6}, 
   Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], MeshStyle -> Opacity[.8],  
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   PlotPoints -> 25, RegionFunction -> (f2[#] <= #2 <= f1[#] &), 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> viewpoint, ImageSize -> Medium];

plt2 = ParametricPlot3D[{{x, f1[x], z f3[x]}, {x, f2[x], z f3[x]}}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]],
      Directive[Green, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]]}];

polygon[a_] := Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Opacity[.3, Blue], 
   Polygon[{{a, f1[a], 0}, {a, f1[a], f3[a]}, {a, f2[a], f3[a]}, {a, f2[a], 0}}]}]

plt2d[a_] := ParametricPlot[{x, v f1[x] + (1 - v) f2[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Opacity[1], Green, Thick]}, 
     {1, Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick]}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue, PlotPoints -> 30,
  Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{a, #[a]} & /@ {f2, f1}]}]

Manipulate[Row[{plt2d[a], Show[plt1, plt2, polygon[a]]}, Spacer[10]],
 {{a, 1}, -5, 5, 1/50}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your code for some reason crashes my mathematica kernel, I'll give you an example with a shorter, lighter code that can be easily adapted to your case:

```
plt1[a_] := Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 10}];
plt2[a_] := Plot[Cos[a*x], {x, 0, 10}];

Manipulate[
 Grid[{{plt1[a], plt2[a]}}, ItemSize -> {{30, 30}}, Frame -> All, 
  FrameStyle -> Red], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}]
```

> [image]

This should translate to your example as follows:

1) Remove manipulate from t1 and t4:

```
t1[a_] := Show[B1, B2, B3, B4[a], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.3}];

t4[a_] := Show[t2, t3[a]];
```

2) Add manipulate in the final Grid

```
  Manipulate[Grid[{{t1[a], t4[a]}}, ItemSize -> {{30, 30}}, Frame -> All, 
     FrameStyle -> Red], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Show[B1, B2, B3, B4[a], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.3}], Show[t2, t3[a]]}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{30, 30}}], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}]
```

(Please format the item size accordingly)